# Append element to QueryList Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, append

Is there a way to append a new element to a QueryList?

For example, i have a QueryList like this:

```
@ContentChildren(SysColumn) syscolumns: QueryList<SysColumn>;
```

And i need to append another SysColumn after the view init. Is it poossible on Angular? I try to append but it says that is not a function of a QueryList.

Comment: Even if you will be able to do It angular will recalculate collection during  next change detection cycle. You can create another collection and work with it.

Comment: How can i create another collection?

Comment: `const myColumns = [...this.syscolumns.toArray()]`

Comment: But i don't know what is the purpose of your idea

Comment: That's ok, but i dont need it to be an array, i need it to be a QueryList. I have another object who recieves a QueryList, so i need a new QueryList with all the elements, that's why i need it to append the new element to the querylist.

Comment: Which element do you want to add?

Comment: Another SysColum, but is not recieved by the First QueryList.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use `reset` method

```
this.syscolumns.reset([...this.syscolumns.toArray(), this.additionalColumn])
```

**[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jdu4cj?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)**