# Append elements to QueryList (Angular)

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I'm trying to combine two QueryLists. The thing is, I have several mat-options, some of them are given through ng-content outside of the component, the other ones are IN the component. With other words, I get some of them with ViewChildren and the other ones with ContentChildren. I need to get them both in the same list, so the mat-select works correctly.

I'm aware that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47268827/append-element-to-querylist-angular) is quite the same, but it does not work. I tried it several times to merge two QueryLists with .reset, but the content of it always stays the same. Even if I create a new QueryList and just want to add some numbers, it does not work. Are there any solutions for this?

EDIT:

To clarify why I want to do this: I made an own component which looks like this (simplified):

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select>
    <input #searchInput type="search" (keydown)="onKeyDownInput($event)" (input)="onSearchInput($event)"
      class="select-search"/>
      <mat-option class="hidden" disabled></mat-option>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

It's purpose is to provide an search input at the top of the dropdown. The Mat-Options are coming from outside with ng-content. I need this because it can vary what I want to display. There has also be a hidden and disabled mat-option, because otherwise the scroll logic of mat-select doesn't work correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont understand why you want to do this, but what i would do is .changes you get the EventEmitter and there you can subscribe and get the value. This you can do with the other querylist too and then combine it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll try it out and will see if it works. I edited my question so it's more clear for you why I want to do this.